# EndOfStreamExceptin: Zookeeper closes socket while reading additional data

Tags: sockets, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

On looking into logs, found the below zookeeper exception in zookeeper logs,

`EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x6e57b6dd2b7c0015, likely client has closed socket
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:220)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

Is this because of the large file size we are trying to consume and if yes, is there anything we need to configure to prevent zookeeper from closing connection.

Thank you.

Comment: how big is the message you're trying to consume? Kafka sets this to 1mb by default. see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40139635/how-can-i-make-consumer-request-more-than-1mb-records-from-kafka/40139890#40139890)

Comment: @jimijazz Thank you for reply. The message size is around 100 MB, and it's the same as `max.broker.size` property in broker configuration. I am also varying `session.timeout.ms` in consumer, however, still it's failing with same error. Is there any way to find correct `session.timeout.ms` for particular message size ?

Comment: afaik, `session.timeout.ms` is the same no matter the message size. are you also setting `max.partition.fetch.bytes` in your consumer properties to be larger than 100MB?

Comment: Yes, `max.partition.fetch.bytes` is also set to 100 MB. Thanks.